# Two WIFI routers, one dedicated to VPN

Tags: router, vpn, ieee-802.11

I'm guessing the answer to this questions is yes, but I just wanted to check before buying the kit :)

I need to overlay VPN access onto an existing network (standard DSL/Wifi).

I looked at dd-wrt and Tomato, which allow both selective and policy-based routing, but the configuration scripts seem a pain to maintain.

I'm thinking a simple solution might be to buy a second wifi router (with OpenVPN) and configure it as an access point with the first router as its default gateway.

I would then have two wifi networks: one straight out and the other always over the VPN.

There is no requirement for the various connected devices to communicate with each other, so them being on potentially different subnets is not an issue here.

This question essentially boils down to: can I open a VPN tunnel on a router which is not directly touching the WAN?

Comment: Consumer-grade network devices and home networking are off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not. You may have better luck on Super User.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I'll admit the current context is a home network, but if the answer is "yes" then I would consider employing the same solution in our office, where users regularly struggle with their VPN client. The issue basically boils down to: "can I open a VPN tunnel on a router which is not directly touching the WAN". When viewed in those terms, I believe the question might not be as off-topic as you make out.

Comment: Did you read what the Help Center says about this?  **"Off-topic: Configuring Consumer Networking Products
Questions about configuring or using consumer networking products (i.e. a Firewall/Router/Switch/Wireless-AP that does not have an option for a paid support contract)."**

Comment: @RonMaupin For the love of Pete, can you not see the question is divorced from the underlying hardware? It's a question about routers and VPNs **in general**

Comment: I didn't put the question on hold. You need to satisfy the moderators, and, if you have a problem with the decision, take it up in meta. That is all explained in the note above.

Comment: @mike-pennington Any input?